# Seperate String into Two Parts with condition PHP

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I i have similiar strings like this

```
$title1 = 'Bleeding Steel Full Movie HD 720P Free';
```

in this string anything before Full is movie title and i am trying to seperate this string to two parts 'Bleeding Steel' and 'Full Movie HD 720P Free' how i can achieve that thanks in advance

Comment: Is any part of the string fixed, as in it never changes?

Comment: Please provide what you have tried.

Comment: unless you have a constant part in string you can't separate them,

Comment: This is next to impossible; the first words in your second part might very well be part of the movie title. How would you determine what is and what is not part of the title?

Comment: in the string where you reach at full and the rest  is not movie title.

Comment: This seems `exif` related. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.exif.php am I right? If so, there's an easy way to do this. If not, then where and how is this data coming from?

Comment: Full Metal Jacket?

Comment: @jeroen Ouhhh.. that's heavy ;-)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I would guess the data is coming from some kind of torrent tracker :-)

Comment: 'Full Movie HD 720P Free' in all strings i want to seperate this . i meant this with full

Comment: @jeroen Maybe. [This is my guess.....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48687795/seperate-string-into-two-parts-with-condition-php#comment84373667_48687795) and asking for clarification also.

Comment: its not from torrent tracker

Comment: that ^ @jeroen I believe was intended for you, but failed to respond to mine, *sigh*

Comment: at this point in time, the post is unclear *and* too broad; see the answers then. I'm out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex for this:

```
<?php
$value = 'Bleeding Steel Full Movie HD 720P Free';

preg_match('/\sFull\sMovie/', $value, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

$offset = !empty($match) ? $match[0][1] : strlen($value);

$value = [
    'title' => substr($value, 0, $offset), 
    'junk' => substr($value, $offset)
];

print_r($value);
```

https://3v4l.org/ICt9c

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [title] => Bleeding Steel
    [junk] =>  Full Movie HD 720P Free
)
```

Comment: As long as no movie is created called `Full Movie Full Movie HD 720P Free` it should work fine. https://3v4l.org/Dm1bo

Comment: thanks mate this what i needed :)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple answers, like 1 option is:

```
trim(substr($title1,0,15));

trim(substr($title1,15));
```

It defends on the fixed and variable part of the string.

EDIT:

with preg_match:

```
<?php
$title1 = 'Bleeding Steel Full Movie HD 720P Free';

preg_match('/(.*)Full Movie/',$title1,$output);

echo $output[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

## Explode is faster

I the simple case I would prefer explode over regular expressions. It is faster according to the documentation and much more simple to use:

> If you don't need the power of regular expressions, you can choose
>   faster (albeit simpler) alternatives like explode() or str_split().

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

```
$title = 'Bleeding Steel Full Movie HD 720P Free';
$delimiter = "Full Movie";
$parts = explode("Full Movie", $title);

# Output: Bleeding Steel - Full Movie HD 720P Free
printf("%s - %s %s", trim($parts[0]), $delimiter, trim($parts[1]));
```